# QuerySelector Not Working in Rails Webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I have the following JavaScript loaded into Webpacker:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
  alert("This shows up.");
  var someObject = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="thing"]');
})();
```

I know that the file is loaded into Webpacker correctly and is executed because I see the alert `This shows up.`. However, when I go into the console, `someObject` is an empty array despite the page containing an object with the `data-toggle` attribute.

I don't see any errors in the console to help diagnose the issue.

I am guessing that the problem involves the script executing before the page is loaded? However, I'm not sure how to remedy that situation when using Rails 6 with Webpacker...

Any assistance would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to wrap your code in an [event listener callback that will execute when the DOM is loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event). This may be the case if your script tag is in the `<head>`; it executes before the rest of the page is loaded.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (_event) => {
  let someObject = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="thing"]');
});
```

You also don't necessarily need to wrap your code in an IIFE (i.e., `(function() { })()` because each file in webpack is (typically) treated as module with its own function scope.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @rossta! 

How can I use the variables defined in the event listener in the JavaScript function loaded by Webpacker in that case? If I add the event listener to `application.js` or on the page, it's still undefined in the JavaScript function loaded by Webpacker.

Comment: Hi Justin, I don’t follow. Sounds likes a separate question.